# How to find duration in seconds from an interval day to second object in Databricks

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, timedate

In a Databricks SQL query, I am creating a column to get the difference in Timestamps of successive rows. I use something like the following,

```
select
  (Timestamp - (LAG(Timestamp, 1) OVER (partition by colA order by Timestamp))) tdiff,
  * 
from 
  the_table
```

But this gives me value of type `interval day to second` like `{"seconds": 180, "nano": 0, "negative": false, "zero": false, "units": ["SECONDS", "NANOS"]}`

How can I get it converted to seconds. For this example, I should basically see 180.

Comment: Have you tried timediff (https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/timediff.html) with SECOND as the unit?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. That is only DBR 14 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in earlier runtimes (tested at least for 13.2) datediff supports the seconds unit.

https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/datediff3.html

This just generates some random ids with multiple values and a fuzzed time to show the syntax.

Also shows equivalent extract from interval as originally posed.

```
%sql
with some_ids_and_random_ints as (
  select
    id,
    floor(rand(5) * 1000) random_int
  from
    range(1000) AS t
),
force_dups_on_id as (
  select
    mod(id, 10) as id_with_dups,
    timestampadd(second, random_int, current_timestamp()) as some_time
  from
    some_ids_and_random_ints
),
result_compare as (
select
  *,
  datediff(
    second,
    lag(some_time) over (
      partition by id_with_dups
      order by
        some_time
    ),
    some_time
  ) as diff_inbuilt_function,
  (some_time - (LAG(some_time, 1) OVER (partition by id_with_dups order by some_time))) tdiff_as_interval
from
  force_dups_on_id
order by
  id_with_dups,
  some_time
)
select id_with_dups,
       some_time,
       diff_inbuilt_function,
       cast(extract(second from tdiff_as_interval) as integer) as seconds_from_interval
  from result_compare
```